# banshee audio player won't start?

Tags: linux-mint

When I try to run banshee, nothing happens and the only log in syslog is:

> ptrace of non-child pid 29619 was attempted by: gdb (pid 29623)

Also `ps aux | grep bansh` shows nothing.

Maybe I'm in the wrong forum, cause I'm using Linux Mint 13 Maya LTS.
Other hints may be that last week I used only PC suspend each day. From time to time (once in a day), the banshee player quits itself at the end of a song without any pattern.

#### UPDATE #1

This comes out when running banshee from CLI:

```
Stacktrace:


Native stacktrace:

    banshee() [0x4916ba]
    banshee() [0x4e0d4f]
    banshee() [0x41bc77]
    /lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libpthread.so.0(+0xfcb0) [0x7f03e283fcb0]
    [0xa58670]

Debug info from gdb:

Could not attach to process.  If your uid matches the uid of the target
process, check the setting of /proc/sys/kernel/yama/ptrace_scope, or try
again as the root user.  For more details, see /etc/sysctl.d/10-ptrace.conf
ptrace: Operation not permitted.
No threads.

=================================================================
Got a SIGSEGV while executing native code. This usually indicates
a fatal error in the mono runtime or one of the native libraries 
used by your application.
=================================================================

Aborted
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try restarting. If it still doesn't work, it might help if you reinstall `mono`. If it still doesn't work, try uninstalling and reinstalling `banshee`.

Comment: yes, i'm sure the restart would help, i just have so many stuff on i cannot lost due to restart. btw, reinstall intself didn't help

Comment: mono reinstall did the fix `sudo apt-get install --reinstall mono-runtime`

Answer (score 1):

Looks like runtime errors in `mono`.

You can try upgrading `mono` and `banshee`to their bleeding edge versions.